# New SPI TFT LCD display requires different kernel.img?

Tags: drivers, kernel, display, raspberrypi

I recently bought a TFT LCD (SPI) display for a Raspberry Pi. The instructions point to http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html

My LCD has Version 6.1 on the back, it is 3.5", 480x320 and I am running Ubuntu (latest version as of this post).

I don't know how to install the drivers for this LCD. They show 'Driver', 'IMG' and 'Ubuntu' links for SPI - V6.1 V6.2 v6.3

Reading the scripts inside these libraries shows that kernel.img and kernel7.img will get overwritten with the one provided in the LCD library.

I'm not a Linux guru by any means, but replacing kernel.img with an unknown version like this just doesn't seem entirely safe to me.

The seller's description says that the drivers will not work and I should only download/install the IMG. I haven't done that yet because I'm not understanding how (why) the kernel.img needs to be changed for this LCD.

**From the instructions:**

- Install win32diskimager and write the IMG file on the Micro SD card.
- Insert the Micro SD Card to your Raspberry Pi board.

My SD card has all of my files and configurations on it - Apache, DNS, WiFi/network, etc. By following their instructions I end up wiping my system clean just to support this LCD?

Do Ubuntu updates replace kernel.img? So, even if I were to perform the install it might (might likely?) get replaced which will render the LCD useless - unless I overwrite kernel.img again?

Can anyone tell me if this is recommended or not and what kinds of issues I'll be in for if I do?

This LCD is SPI, TFT, 3.5", 480x320. Version is 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this SPI TFT LCD display working by following the instructions on this page:

http://osoyoo.com/2016/09/13/install-raspberry-pi-3-5-touch-screen-driver-for-raspbian-jessie/

Don't forget to enable SPI on the Pi using raspi-config.

Everything works great. I installed matchbox-keyboard to display a small keyboard on the display using these instructions:

http://ozzmaker.com/virtual-keyboard-for-the-raspberry-pi/?utm_source=feedly

But... I'm still not sure if it was the right thing to do in replacing kernel.img and kernel7.img - or how this effects me in future Ubuntu updates. If anyone is able to shed some light on these 2 files and how replacing them effects future updates please comment and let me know!